# Checking for one of the candlestick patterns in TradingView pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, trading, algorithmic-trading

I am working on a TradingView strategy that relies on using their pre-defined candlestick patterns i.e. from the view below

[image]

I want to check if certain candle stick pattern occurred inside my pinescript. After googling for a while I wasn't able to find "easy" solution for this, most involve calculating these manually. I wanted to ask if it is possible to do this via some sort of prebuilt helper function i.e. like `ema` or `macd` we have in pinescript, but for specific candle pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not through built-in functions in Pine, but the code of all the indies you're showing in your question is made available by TradingView. To access it, load the indicator corresponding to the pattern of your choice on the chart, then use the "Source code" button to open its source code in the Editor:

[image]

From there, you can copy/paste the code in your own script.